# How to distinct rows without using Distinct

Tags: sql-server, group-by, duplicates, distinct

i am new in sql i use MS SQL Server, i have this select and joins

```
SELECT t1.number
    ,t2.site1 
    ,t2.Events_W
    ,t3.site1
    ,t3.Events_W_D
    ,t4.site1
    ,t4.Events_NW
    ,t5.site1
    ,t5.Events_NW_D
    FROM [TEST].[ak].[test3] AS t1
LEFT JOIN [TEST].[ak].[test2] AS T2
    ON t1.number=t2.number AND t1.Events_W = t2.Events_W 
LEFT JOIN [TEST].[ak].[test2] AS t3
    ON t1.number=t3.number  AND t1.Events_W_D=t3.Events_W_D 
LEFT JOIN [TEST].[ak].[test2] as t4
    ON t1.number=t4.number AND t1.Events_NW = t4.Events_NW 
LEFT JOIN [TEST].[ak].[test2] t5
    ON t1.number=t5.number AND t1.Events_NW_D=t5.Events_NW_D
```

The result is this:

```
Number  Site    |event_w    |site   |event_w_d  |site   |Event_nt   |site   |event_nw_d
anum    |2014   |116    |2014   |99     |2358   |163    |2087   |129
bnum    |1570   |17     |1570   |76     |1196   |99     |1196   |577
bnum    |1570   |17     |1905   |111    |1508   |26     |1508   |427
bnum    |1196   |3      |1475   |2      |1508   |1      |8263   |5
cnum    |2087   |15     |NULL   |NULL   |2087   |92     |NULL   |NULL
dnum    |1071   |14     |1905   |106    |1071   |21     |1426   |206
gnum    |2087   |36     |2087   |97     |2087   |92     |2087   |93
rnum    |123    |23     |123    |23     |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
```

the right result must be this:

```
Number  |Site   |event_w    |site   |event_w_d  |site   |Event_nt   |site   |event_nw_d
anum    |2014   |116    |2014   |99     |2358   |163    |2087   |129
bnum    |1196   |3      |1475   |2      |1508   |1      |8263   |5
cnum    |2087   |15     |NULL   |NULL   |2087   |92     |NULL   |NULL
dnum    |1071   |14     |1905   |106    |1071   |21     |1426   |206
gnum    |2087   |36    |2087    |97     |2087   |92    |2087    |93
```

i need to distinct by numbers but without using '**Distinct**'.

Help Please!

Comment: Why do you not want to use `DISTINCT`?
When you want to "eliminate" rows you have to use either `GROUP BY` (typically when using an aggregate), `DISTINCT`, or some other method (such as using a derived table with `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER`). Are there criteria you want to use to "rank" records within a `number` so you can pick which one you want to have returned?

Comment: What are your conditions arriving at the output result ? Also I notice there is no 'rnum' row in your O/P.

Comment: My Database expert told me eliminate duplicates but without using distinct, but i never do this before without distinct.

Comment: conditions  my conditions are to take SITE where  some number have most EVENTS but when Number have equal event on SITE make Duplicates

Comment: Seems to me like you are looking for `group by` and not `distinct`. Your current results *are* distinct - there are no duplicate rows in them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Declare @Tep Table
(
name varchar(100), City Varchar(500), Contct1 bigInt)

INSERT INTO @Tep
select 'R', 'Delhi', 7827492235
Union All
select 'S', 'Noida', 8827492235

Union All
select 'P', 'Noida', 7827492235

Union All
select 't', 'r', 9827492235

--Get Unique Record Without Distinct
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Contct1 ORDER BY Contct1) As RowID, 
name, 
City , Contct1
FROM @Tep
)T  WHERE RowID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try below approch Get Unique Record Without Distinct
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Contct1 ORDER BY Contct1) As RowID, 
name, 
City , Contct1
FROM @Tep
)T  WHERE Contct1 NOT In (

SELECT Contct1 FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Contct1 ORDER BY Contct1) As RowID, 
name, 
City , Contct1
FROM @Tep
)T where RowID =2
)

also try this way